# How to process an image in url to upload on the server in cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am having a problem with this code. i wanna process the cordova android image url ( ie. stored in localStorage ) to upload in my web server.

```
function processImages(list, i){
    var images = list[i].images;
    images && images.forEach(function(image, j){
      window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(image, function(entry) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                list[i].images[j] = evt.target.result;
            }
            reader.onerror = function(evt) {
                alert("error");
            }
            entry.file(function(f) {
                //alert("Image is added");
                reader.readAsDataURL(f);
            }, function(e) {
                alert('Image process error : '+e);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

This code runs good if i am enabling #alert("Image is added"); this alert.
without this alert the app is shutting down by giving error unfortunately appname has stopped.

Its also not working for n number of images of size more than 2mb.

Note : consider async call and image size is more than 2mb each minimum 10 image per record.

Please help me !!!

Thanks

Comment: It might not directly related with your problem but the varibale j is always: j+1 == images when the callback is called. Try an IIFE around window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI to pass image and j. example: (function(img, index){ window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI ..... })(image, j);

Comment: I didn't get you please edit in that code for better understanding of me

Comment: Sorry for my answer is not working. May be the method resolveLocalFileSystemURL does the job instead of resolveLocalFileSystemURI that is deprecated.